# Definition of 'Maximal Length of Presentation'

Tags: commutative-algebra

In exercise 1.2.6 of the french version (seems like it is also the case of the english version) of *Algebre Commutative* by Bourbaki, a function $\lambda$ was defined to assign each $R$-module the maximal length of its presentation. Here, the presentation (of length $n$) is defined to be an exact sequence $L_n \to L_{n-1} \to \cdots \to L_0 \to M \to 0$, with $L_i$ finitely generated and free and no other restrictions, and $\lambda(M)$ is the least upper bound for integers $n$ such that $M$ admits a presentation of length $n$. When $M$ is not finitely generated, let $\lambda(M)=-1$. My question is that, is this indeed well-defined?

Given two exact sequences $E \to N \to 0$ and $0 \to A \to B$, one can 'glue' them together: $E \to N \to A \to B$ with the connecting morphism $N \to A$ defined to be $0$. Therefore, we are able to infinitely extend **any** presentation... Right?

In my mind, the correct definition should be:

$\lambda(M)$ is the minimal $n$ such that $M$ admits an exact sequence  $0 \to L_n \to L_{n-1} \to \cdots \to L_0 \to M \to 0$ with $L_i$ free.

**Edit:**

Well, it seems like the definitions the book is giving and I am giving are unrelated. There was a *Prove that for any module $M$ over a noetherian ring $R$, $\lambda(M)$ equals $\infty$ or $-1$.*

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, your method allows you to extend the exacte sequence *to the right*, while you want to extend it *to the left*.

Given a resolution $L_n\to \dots\to L_0\to M\to 0$ and an exact sequence $0\to A\to B$, you can indeed write an exact sequence
$$L_n\to \dots\to L_0\to M\to A \to B$$
but that is no longer a resolution of $M$.

To extend the resolution to the left, you need some morphism $L_{n+1}\to L_n$ (with $L_{n+1}$ free of finite rank)  which is surjective on the kernel of $L_n\to L_{n-1}$. This exists if and only if this kernel is finitely generated, which is guaranteed when $R$ is noetherian (as it is a submodule of $L_n$), but not in general.

Comment: Ah yes- the $\lambda$ here defines how far a module is from being 'infinite' in some sense, while my definition measures how far a module is from being free. Those are unrelated.

Comment: I don't know if I would say "infinite", since the zero module satisfies this property (saying that the zero module is infinite is sort of weird). Basically you are looking at a stronger property, namely that not only does there exist an infinite free resolution of finite rank, but all the terms are $0$ if you go far enough on the left. This is obviously stronger than $\lambda(M)=\infty$, and then given this property, you are asking which is the minimal number of steps before all modules in the resolution are $0$. So it's not unrelated, but it is different.